# How to get an persistant workspace with database on eclipse che hosted on che.openshift.io

Tags: mysql, eclipse-che

I recently changed to Eclipse Che on che.openshift.io
I found out how to set an workspace as persistent, so the changed code remains and you don't always have to check in in your repository before you leave.

But I could not find out how to get my MySQL database beeing persistent. I always have to build it up from the ground.

Any suggestions? I could not find anything in the net. Maybe its possible with a special workspace config Devfile?

Comment: To have more attention you can ask a question in the public [Eclipse Che](https://mattermost.eclipse.org/eclipse/channels/eclipse-che) channel

Answer (score 0):

As the guys from [Eclipse Che Channel](https://mattermost.eclipse.org/eclipse/channels/eclipse-che) explained, it's possible by following this [Eclipse Che Doc](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/end-user-guide/making-a-workspace-portable-using-a-devfile/#_persistent_storage) using Devfile Options.

Since this seems not as easy for me as expected, I first have to get familiar with it before providing an working example and instructions how to get it run.